# How to remove toolbar margin-bottom?

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar, android-toolbar

**Hey guys !

is there any way to remove margin bottom of the toolbar?
as you see in the image, i have two toolbars that both of them have margins. and i need to remove margin bottom of the first toolbar. Any ideas ?**
[image: Click here]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                cardview:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                cardview:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                cardview:cardElevation="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_icon"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textColorHint="#727272"
                        android:textDirection="rtl" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding

```
android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
```

to the `toolbar`.

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem ! my problem is the toolbars margins or (paddings) can i some how remove them ?

Comment: nothing  changed. I think these are for right and left parts of the toolbar, do you have any solution for the bottom part ??

Comment: you can try adding `android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"`...for the `RelativeLayout` layout containg the `CardView`..

Answer (score 1):

Try using single `Toolbar` and put your title `TextView` and search `CardView` inside it.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="24dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingStart="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    cardview:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                    cardview:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    cardview:cardElevation="0dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_icon"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textColorHint="#727272"
                            android:textDirection="rtl" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Just add `android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"` to your `toolbar2`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i need to make two toolbars, because i wanna hide the first one on scroll down and make second one visible always. as you see in the code i have posted , i added      ' app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" ' for the first toolbar, but not the second one

Comment: Ohh then you can just add `android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"` to your `toolbar2` to get this behavior